# Excel VBA squeezes arrays passed to function

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as follows:

```vb
Function udf() As Variant
    udf = udfWithArg(getArray())
End Function

Function udfWithArg(arg) As Variant
    udfWithArg = arg
End Function

Function getArray() As Variant
    'getArray = Array(Array(1), Array(2))
    getArray = Array(Array(1, 2))
End Function
```

If I call `=udf()` from excel - it works fine - getting 2D array as a result.

If I call `=udfWithArgs(getArray())` - VBA squeezes 2D array to 1D. Squeezing happens for 1 row arrays (doesn't happen for one column array).

Why is that? Is it possible to prevent VBA from squeezing?

**Edit:**

Addressing a comment from @Ike - my understanding is that Array(Array(1, 2)) is 2D:

[image]

Anyway it is different from `arg` within `udfWithArg`:

[image]

Comment: Can you give some sample data? For me it works as expected.

Comment: @Ike - no data needed. You can see dimensions when debugging - add a breakpoint to `usdWithArgs` and add `arg` to watch. You can see that it is 1D when calling `=udfWithArgs(getArray())` from Excel

Comment: `Array`-function always returns a one-dimensional array! So your `Array(Array(1, 2))` returns a one-dimensional array with`Ubound` = 0 with `getArray(0)` returning a one-dimensional array - having two elements --> `Ubound` = 1

Comment: Sorry, but your understanding of the `Array`-function is wrong - see also @notus_pandas answer. E.g. a range like A1:C3 is a 2-dimensional array. But you can't create a two-dimensional array with `Array`-function. `Dim arg(2,4) as variant` will create an empty 2D-Array.

Comment: Also, you're showing it to yourself but looking at it wrong, I feel. a = Variant(0 To 0), a(0) (we're stepping into your second Array() here) has Variant(0 To 1) aka 2 elements (in this case 1 and 2). In both cases those are 1Dimensional. If your intended question is "Why does VBA simplify the 1D(1D(2EL)) to 1D(2EL), then I can't answer that, however, I also don't see a problem with it. When you'd use `getArray = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))` you'd effectively be passing a 2D array to udfWithArgs

Comment: Added a screenshot of how it'd be if you'd use the 2 1D arrays in the 1D array. Best I can assume is VBA seeing your example as a 1D array with 2 elements because there's nothing else in the outer 1D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an elaboration to what Ike was saying, I wanted to fiddle a bit to show it more clearly, however you mentioned "column array" so I'm sure you've meddled with it yourself a bit as well.

Regardless, I've made the udfWithArgs to check if it's a 1D or 2D array and change it where necessary:

```
Function udf() As Variant
    udf = udfWithArg(getArray())
End Function

Function udfWithArg(arg) As Variant
    Dim arr(), uBoundArg, i As Long
    On Error GoTo skipTo1Dim
        uBoundArg = UBound(arg, 2) 'this will error when it's a 1D-array
        arr = arg
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo skipEnd
skipTo1Dim:
    ReDim arr(1 To 1, LBound(arg) To UBound(arg)) 'to retain its row-like array structure
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(1, i) = arg(i)
    Next i
skipEnd:
    Debug.Print "LBound of 1st Dimension: " & LBound(arr, 1) & " and UBound: " & UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print "LBound of 2nd Dimension: " & LBound(arr, 2) & " and UBound: " & UBound(arr, 2)
    udfWithArg = arr
End Function

Function getArray() As Variant
    'getArray = Array(Array(1), Array(2))
    getArray = Array(Array(1, 2))
End Function

Function getArray2() As Variant
    getArray2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B7").Value
End Function
```

Here's an example of the usage, A1:B1 was originally the way you had it and how I have it with the `ReDim arr(1 To 1, LBound(arg) To UBound(arg))` and G1:G2 is how it'd be if you'd reverse the dimensions

[image: usage of udfWithArgs(getArray2())]

This is merely to "force the antisqueeze" even though the squeeze wasn't really happening as Ike mentioned: 1D(1D(2elements)).

**Edit:**
Here's when you'd be passing 2 1D arrays in a 1D array:

[image: 2D instead of 1D]

Comment: thanks, I followed the same approach, so it looks like there is no way to avoid unsqueezing

Comment: Like I said, I don't see a problem with it since it doesn't affect your outcome per se and you can catch it being 1D as shown in my code :)